# Ruby on Rails Guide "Getting Started with Rails" - Step 5.7 - UnknowAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails by doing this tutorial. Everything went fine and smooth until step 5.7.

I doublechecked all files, but they are identical with the ones presented in the tuturial.

Again and again I get following message:

> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ArticlesController#create
>
> unknown attribute: title

my articles_controller.rb:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

my new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Das ist ein Test für einen neuen Artikel</h1>

<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

my db-rename file, 20150427182002_create_articles:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :titel
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I am sitting now for about two hours in front of this step and code, and don't get it.

Thank you all in advance for helping me out.

---

Thanks a bunch! The rollback was the point. I tried to "remigrate" but did not do a rollback.

Comment: `:titel` is not how you spell `:title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t.string :titel` should be `t.string :title` in the migration file.

Then `rake db:rollback` to roll back the previous version of database then `rake db:migrate` to apply the new changes.

Comment: thank you Mab and PSkocik for the hint. I changed that, but still get the same message:

unknown attribute: title

Comment: Try with the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
rake db:reset
```

to rerun the migrations.

Comment: An important note to add is that this command will wipe out all of the data in the database.